# How to disable submit button while form is processing and reenable once finished?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have found a lot of questions like this but none answer my question.

I have HTML like this:

```
<form action="..">
  <input type="submit" value="download" />
</form>
```

The form takes a few seconds to generate and download the file.

**How do I disable submit button while the form is being processed and reenable once finished? I know how to disable it, but how do I catch that the form has done processing?**

My solution was to replace the form submit with a manual ajax call, like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  disableButton();
  $.get(form_action, function() {
    enableButton()
    // how to force browser to download a file ?
  });
  return false;
});
```

So I have two solutions and both of them suck.

1. One is to catch a click or submit event but I do not know when the
   form finished
2. Two is manual ajax call which doesnt let me to download the file

Comment: @Triode aaaaaand? How the input will be reenabled once the form will complete processing?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask for the download file do you have an extra ULR? Not the same as your form action URL.

If you can create a new URL to download the file, instead of writing bytes directly to the ajax response,
then maybe we can use an iFrame to download the file.

So the solution should be:
1 Use ajax send an file download post request.
  -> Create the file in Server side

2 After server side finished, return an address of the target file.

3 In the success method, create a new iFrame using the file URL.
  -> Here, if the content-type (MIME type) is correct, browser will show the download diaglog.

In server side, we need some space to save the file and a process to delete the file.

I haven't done this before... Just a suggestion. :P

Comment: I will try iframe method. I tried opening new window() with the URL to the file but that's just a failure. Thanks :)

Comment: In fact, I think open a new window to download is the same as iFrame src. What is the content-type of your file?

Comment: It differs from passed parameters

Comment: OK. Good luck! :) If it still doesn't work, paste the content-type in the HTML header, and we can have a look. :)